# Woocommerce Customisation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am a total novice and need help.  I have read other posts and can copy and paste code into .php files but need specific help if anyone can :)

I am using latest versions of WordPress and woocommerce.

During checkout for a subscription it says:

> £138.96 on September 1st each year and a £110.96 sign-up fee

I want it to say:

> £110.96 today, less any promotional discounts; renewable annually
>   subject to continued eligibility at £138.96 per year on 1st September

Any ideas or help?

Comment: Are you using a subscription extension for woocommerce, if so perhaps drop the plugin author an email and ask if they provide a hook to customise that text.

Answer (score 0):

I think a image to the actual Checkout page would be more useful.
You can add text to some Sections of the code using Hooks.
It dependes where you want it to put it.
This may help you
https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-checkout-page/